# Laravel 4 User Profile Link

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I currently have a route that looks like this:

```
Route::get('/profile/{username}',array(
    'as' => 'profile',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@getProfile'
));
```

The idea is that a link, like `http://www.website-here.com/profile/johnnyappleseed`, containing a `username` will do a search for the username in the database and return the profile that matches based on the username in the URL. How would I create a link to the logged in User's profile using the same route. Currently I have 
 `<li><a href="profile/{{ Auth::user()->username }}">Profile</a></li>` 
But that seems incorrect and that there should be a way to do it using some of Laravels helpers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`route`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls) helper and pass the route name and an array of parameters needed:

```
<li>
    <a href="{{ route('profile', [Auth::user()->username]) }}">
        Profile
    </a>
</li>
```

If you want to go all the way and use even more Laravel helpers, you can use the `HTML` facade and generate the entire link tag in one line:

```
<li>
    {{ HTML::link(route('profile', [Auth::user()->username]), 'Profile') }}
<li>
```